# PWA Add to homepage - "duplication glitch"

Tags: progressive-web-apps

I'm currently working on enhancing a web app with some cooler features. I started small and added a manifest file and a service worker to handle Add to Homescreen and show a offline page when no internet connection.
One thing I notice is that you can end up with a lot of homescreen icons of the same app (it's possible I might be doing something wrong).

Is there a way to avoid this? In an ideal world sequential add to homescreen would replace the previous shortcut.

Test on Nexus 5x + Chrome 58

Thanks

Comment: Try sharing some code which handles the Add to Homescreen part. While you're at it, check the [The New and Improved Add to Home screen](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/02/improved-add-to-home-screen).